# Receiving MSMQ Transactions As a Group

Tags: c#, transactions, msmq

I'm currently having to send files over the size of 4MB through several servers using MSMQ. The files are initially sent in chunks, like so:

```
        using (MessageQueueTransaction oTransaction = new MessageQueueTransaction())
            {

                // Begin the transaction
                oTransaction.Begin();

                // Start reading the file
                using (FileStream oFile = File.OpenRead(PhysicalPath))
                {

                    // Bytes read
                    int iBytesRead;

                    // Buffer for the file itself
                    var bBuffer = new byte[iMaxChunkSize];

                    // Read the file, a block at a time
                    while ((iBytesRead = oFile.Read(bBuffer, 0, bBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {

                        // Get the right length
                        byte[] bBody = new byte[iBytesRead];
                        Array.Copy(bBuffer, bBody, iBytesRead);

                        // New message
                        System.Messaging.Message oMessage = new System.Messaging.Message();

                        // Set the label
                        oMessage.Label = "TEST";

                        // Set the body
                        oMessage.BodyStream = new MemoryStream(bBody);

                        // Log
                        iByteCount = iByteCount + bBody.Length;
                        Log("Sending data (" + iByteCount + " bytes sent)", EventLogEntryType.Information);

                        // Transactional?
                        oQueue.Send(oMessage, oTransaction);

                    }

                }

                // Commit
                oTransaction.Commit();

            }
```

These messages are sent from Machine A to Machine B, and then forwarded to Machine C. However, I've noticed that the PeekCompleted event on Machine B is triggered before all messages are sent.

For example, a test run just now showed 8 messages sent, and were processed on Machine B in groups of 1, 1 and then 6.

I presume this is due to the transactional part ensuring the messages arrive in exactly the right order, but not guaranteeing they are all collected at exactly at the same time.

The worry I have is that when Machine B passes the messages to Machine C, these now count as 3 separate transactions, and I'm unsure as to whether the transactions themselves are delivered in the correct order (for example, 1 then 6 then 1).

My question is, is it possible to receive messages using PeekCompleted by transaction (meaning, all 8 messages are collected first), and pass them on so Machine C gets all 8 messages together? Even in a system where multiple transactions are being sent at the same time?

Or are the transactions themselves guaranteed to arrive in the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

I think I missed this when looking at the topic:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811055.aspx

> That these messages will either be sent together, in the order they
>   were sent, or not at all. In addition, consecutive transactions
>   initiated from the same machine to the same queue will arrive in the
>   order they were committed relative to each other. Moreover

So, no matter how diluted the transactions get, the order will never be affected.

Comment: The order of the messages will be maintained but I'm not 100% sure about them being queued consecutively if there are multiple simultaneous transactions.